# Folium choropleth polylines categorical values from a GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, folium, choropleth

I am trying to use Folium to create a map of water pipes. The data is in a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame with polyline geometry. Each pipe has a categorical value.

I would like to color the pipes according to this categorical value and display a legend for this.

Is the choropleth function only for polygons? The fill_color argument does not do anything (maybe because lines cannot be filled?)

The below code just displays the polylines as black. I know that this is intended for a numeric value. I am asking for a code example to do this for a categorial value.

```
m = folium.Map(location=loc, zoom_start=11,
           tiles="cartodbpositron")
m.choropleth(
geo_data=pipes,
name='Test_data',
data=pipes,
columns=['ID', 'Zone'],
key_on='feature.properties.ID',
fill_color='YlGn',
line_weight = 2,
smooth_factor=100,
legend_name='Zones'
).add_to(m)
```

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried ?